# How to handle a named parameter and @keyword in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I use the Robot framework with Python and Linux.

I don't know how to use the optional named parameter `b` and `c` in the decorator. Can somebody explain?

See example below:

```
@keyword('Starting a "${a}" b "${b}"?? c "${c}"??')
def Start(self, a, b='', c=''):
   foo
```

Comment: this is just a dummy line

Comment: Why use the decorator in this instance? Why not just use the keyword `Start` (eg: `Start  arg_a  arg_b  arg_c`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand your question, you're trying to create a keyword with embedded arguments, which would have default args - and this is not allowed, [doc link, the last paragraph in Basic Syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name).

What you could do is to leave up for the caller to pass on "the default" values; e.g.:

```
@keyword('Starting a "${a}" b "${b}" c "${c}"')
def Start(self, a, b, c):
   # just work with a, b, c, they *always* have _some_ value when called from RF
   foo
```

---

```
# later on, used in Robotframework code:
Starting a "" b "" c ""
```

When called like this ^, the variables `a`, `b` and `c` will be passed to the python function as empty strings - RF defaults arguments to string type, meaning this code inside the function will work in this case:

```
assert a == ''  # will pass when called with no value for a
assert type(b) == str  # this will always work, regardless did b (or a, or c) have a value set in the call, or not
```

Comment: Thx for the answers  and merry Christmas (i am going to read the document during my holliday)

Comment: Please do - the RF user guide is "the Bible" - very well written, practically everything you need to have through knowledge. Merry Christmas :)